# import класса , если страница генерируется PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mvc

Пишу свой фреймворк на PHP и при генерации страницы в нее подключаются нужные файлы из *ajax_modules*

В общем в файле login.js в папке ajax_modules есть сточка
    `import Ajax from '/Modules/js/Ajax';`
В консоли вот такая ошибка:
Что я делаю не так? Если что класс Ajax правильно экпортируется

[image: В консоли такая ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

операция import в браузере не поддерживается. Перед тем как выполнять js-код, вам нужно "собрать" его в один файл. В этом помогут такие утилиты как gulp, amd, webpack и другие.
Рекомендую использовать webpack как наиболее современное решение.

Comment: Слушай чел, спасибо за помощь, нереально ты меня выручил! Только я вероятнее всего напишу свой сборщик файлов на PHP